# PHP numerical descending in database?

Tags: php, database

I have table person.

```
id, name    product_A  product_B
--  -----   ---------  --------- 
1   Joe        1         4        // result product A + Product B = 5
2   Leo        5         1        // result product A + Product B = 6
3   Lia        2         2        // result product A + Product B = 4
```

First, I need to count product A + Product B.

```
function count($a,$b){
$total = $a+$b;
return $total;
}
```

Then call value in database

```
    $count_row = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person ");
    $result_row= mysql_num_rows($count_row);
$i=0;
$j=0;
$k=0;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM person "
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
          $array_a[$i++]=$row['product_A'];
          $array_b[$j++]=$row['product_B'];
          $array_name[$j++]=$row['name'];
        }
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $count_row ; $i++){
$tot[i] = count($array_a,$array_a);
$array_name[i];
}
```

// sorting

```
   function desc($result_row){
    $array = array();
    global $tot;
    for ($n = 0 ; $n <$result_row ; $n++){
        array_push($array,$tot[$n]);
    }
    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($array) ; $i++)
        rsort($array);
                for ($n = 0 ; $n <$result_row ; $n++){
                echo $array_name[$n]."<br>";
                            echo $array[$n]."<br>";
                }
            }

   desc($result_row);
```

Then I want to echoing name based on the highest value or descending of product A + Product B. 
'The output = Leo , Joe, Lia'.
How can I do that in PHP code? Help me please...

Comment: Why don't you sort it at the database and then just print the results? It will be more efficient rather than what you are attempting here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid because in my real case the result of product_A + product_B will always update when user input some data. So, it will be complicated when more than one user input data in the same time. I just try to make a simple question to solve my prob. But it's not easy :(

Comment: It would be better to update your question with the real case, instead of asking solutions for some imagined problem - or, simply, remove the SQL part and adjust your question so it is about sorting arrays and not about database/sum values.

Comment: Go back a few steps, try to explain what you want to achieve without any code  Code is good for showing an attempt but it's somewhat unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The differences of my question and my real case is.. my real case need more calculation, not just sum value in the total function

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I want to echoing the name in database based on the highest value of product_A+product_B. But I want the sum is not by using query, but using function.

Comment: Ok , why not sum by query?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld because in my real case, that is not just count by sum, but more calculations there. So, I have to make function to count the calculation.

Comment: @VictoriaCho - Ok I've supplied a solution that I hope will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<?php
//product array ($products is the array fetched from the db)
$products = array();
$products[0] = array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'Joe', 'productA'=>1, 'productB'=>4);
$products[1] = array('id'=>2, 'name'=>'Leo', 'productA'=>5, 'productB'=>1);
$products[2] = array('id'=>3, 'name'=>'Lia', 'productA'=>2, 'productB'=>2);

//Create a single-column array with sums
$productSum = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productSum[] = (int)$product['productA'] + (int)$product['productB'];
}
//Do the magic, sort DESCENDING by $productSum-array into $products-array
array_multisort($productSum, SORT_DESC, $products);

//Output
print_r($products);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Leo [productA] => 5 [productB] => 1 )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Joe [productA] => 1 [productB] => 4 )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Lia [productA] => 2 [productB] => 2 )
)
```

For more info about array_multisort(), take a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Comment: If I have many data on database, Should I write all of product array $products[0],$products[1] and so on from database?

Comment: You could use whlle_mysql_fetch_assoc() and   use syntax echo $row['name']

Comment: thank you... I solve my prob with your code. I just a bit edit your code to solve my real case.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Yoy may try like this

```
SELECT  (tp.product_A + tp.product_B) AS total,tp.name
FROM table_person tp
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Comment: No, I mean I have to count product_A + product_B in PHP without using query. So, at the first I have to call the value of product_A & product_B. Then I count it in PHP. But, I can't echoing the name by the highest result of product_A + product_B. Actually this is not my real case. I just try to make a simple question to solve my problem.

Comment: @VictoriaCho Cho you can get the value as array in php then add the tp.product_A and tp.product_B value and make it a new key and sort the value of new key by DESC.

Comment: Yes, I did. I save the result of product_A + product_B in an array. I can sort the result. But I can't echoing the name after I sort it. The output still same like in table Joe, Leo, Lia.

Comment: `$f[i]; // f is the result from some calculation
function desc($loop){
    $array = array();
 global $f;
    for ($n = 0 ; $n <$loop ; $n++){
        array_push($array,$f[$n]);
    }
    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($array) ; $i++)
        rsort($array);
      for ($n = 0 ; $n <$loop ; $n++){
            echo $array[$n]."<br>";
   }
  }
   desc($loop); `

Comment: @VictoriaCho Cho yes you can it in the question and also show the array structure in code ..

Comment: @VictoriaCho You can sort it while bringing it from the database just modifying the query second thing is you have wrongly placed  `$count_row` in `desc($count_row)`and in `for ($i = 0 ; $i < $count_row ; $i++)` as parameter while the right parameter is `$result_row` which will return the no of rows as per your code.

Comment: Ya, It's `$result_row`. My code just sort the value of product_A + product_B. But I can't echoing the name by desc of the result product_A + product_B.

Comment: @VictoriaCho Cho there is no relationship between $array_name and $array so how it will do it by descending you first need to push the name in $array and then you need to sort and display..currently there is no change in $array_name so it will show as it is...

Comment: if I do `rsort` in $array_name, the result is only sort based on the name of database. I want it show based on `$array` (total Product_A + Product B)

Comment: @VictoriaCho either you can add the `$array_name` as an new key in the new `$array` then sort by total of `(Product_A + Product B)` and display or you can add `(Product_A + Product B)` as a new key in $array_name and then sort the key `(Product_A + Product B)` and display..

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to use suggested SQL that people wrote for you. Doing this in php is not practical for your case. Rather do it in SQL and save yourself some code writing and memory on the server.

Example:

In SQL:

```
SELECT *, product_A  + product_B AS product_sum FROM persons ORDER BY product_sum DESC
```

Then in PHP:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set))
{
    // Results Already will be sorted for you you just have to output them.
    echo $record['name'].' has '.$record['product_sum'].' product sum.';
    echo '<br/>'; 
}
```

And you can output now name or product counts or totals or anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

As a  solution to your problem please try executing the following query.

```
select *,product_A + product_B as total from person order by total desc
```

Comment: In my real case, product_A+product_B can't be count in query. So at the first I  have to call every value product_A & product_B. Then I use a function to count them. Then I get the result of product_A + product_B. I can sort desc the value. But I can't echoing the name after I sort it. The output still same like in table Joe, Leo, Lia.

Comment: It would be better to update your question with the real case, instead of asking solutions for some imagined problem - or, simply, remove the SQL part and adjust your question so it is about sorting arrays and not about database/sum values.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The differences of my question and my real case is.. my real case need more calculation, not just sum value in the total function.